# ROS2 Node Segmentation Fault on Shutdown with Global Node Variable

Tags: c++, gcc, ros2

I'm a beginner with ROS2 Iron and have encountered an issue when attempting to use a node object as a global variable.

I've written a simple demo.cpp as follows:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> global_node;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    // Initialize the global node
    global_node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("demo");

    while (rclcpp::ok())
    {
        rclcpp::spin_some(global_node);
        break;   // The problem also occurs if you remove this break statement and instead use Ctrl+C to terminate the program during execution.
    }

    RCLCPP_INFO(global_node->get_logger(), "shutdown start");
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    RCLCPP_INFO(global_node->get_logger(), "shutdown end");

    return 0;
}
```

After running the node, a segmentation fault occurs upon exit:

```
$ colcon build
$ ros2 run demo demo
[INFO] [1702770442.794800097] [demo]: shutdown start
[INFO] [1702770442.795074660] [demo]: shutdown end
cannot publish data, at ./src/rmw_publish.cpp:62 during '__function__'
Fail in delete datareader, at ./src/rmw_service.cpp:100 during '__function__'
[ros2run]: Segmentation fault
```

Of course, everything works as expected if I don't define the nodes as global variables:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

// std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> global_node;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    // Initialize the global node
    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> global_node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("demo");

    while (rclcpp::ok())
    {
        rclcpp::spin_some(global_node);
        break;
    }

    RCLCPP_INFO(global_node->get_logger(), "shutdown start");
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    RCLCPP_INFO(global_node->get_logger(), "shutdown end");

    return 0;
}
```

Based on debugging, the crash occurs during the destruction of the node object.

Could you please help me understand the reason behind this issue?

From my perspective, in both cases, the node's destruction occurs after `rclcpp::shutdown()`.

My compiler: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Comment: *From my perspective, in both cases, the node's destruction occurs after rclcpp::shutdown().* -- Your global variable is destroyed after `main`'s `}` and who knows what else is destroyed that is dependent on the `shared_ptr` to be alive, or vice-versa.  When you venture outside the `}` and rely on a certain order of object destruction, then all bets are off.

Comment: But in this simple example, could you tell me what else std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> depends on and what depends on it?

Comment: `rclcpp::Node` -- I do not know what this is, so I cannot answer your question.  It more than likely is a type where destruction is not simple, and having it in a shared_ptr that gets destroyed after `main` could be problematic.  To test this, change `rclcpp::Node` to `struct DoNothing {};` and make a `std::shared_ptr<DoNothing>`.  Do you see the same issue when the type is a simple struct?  If there is no issue, then again, it probably is an issue with how `rclcpp::Node` maintains itself during its lifetime.

Comment: Also, that is how you should approached the problem, and that is to cut down the code to the simplest form using a global `shard_ptr` to see if it an issue with `shared_ptr` in general, or an issue with `rclcpp::Node`.

Comment: Yes, the issue is likely in how `rclcpp::Node` is being used. As I mentioned in the question, the segmentation fault occurred inside `rclcpp::Node`'s destructor. `rclcpp` is the C++ development framework provided by ROS2 (Robot Operating System), and `rclcpp::Node` is one of the most common classes within it. Since I am new to ROS development, I had some doubts. I realize you may not be very familiar with ROS2 either. Nevertheless, thank you for your response and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

rclcpp::shutdown() destroys the nodes created in the scope in this case the main function. All the nodes which are declared globally should be manually destroyed in the main function.